# Java Convert string array to list

Tags: java, arrays, string

I have the following string and would like to convert it to string array

```
String singleArray = "[501]"
String multipleArray = "[1,501,634]"
```

I would like to get `List<String>` from that,
the thing is sometimes it can be a single value
and sometimes it can be multiple value seperate by comma.

I tried to use `Arrays.asList(multipleArray)` but it didn't work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried something using String.split? Careful it takes a regex as an argument.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about

```
String arr [] = str.replace("[", "").replace ("]", "").split (",");
```

And then as per your knowledge, you can use the array to create a List using

```
Arrays.asList(arr);
```

**Note**

As noted by Bas.E, my solution works upon the data as per your example.

Comment: What about `String str = "[1, '[501]', 634]"` ? The OP never stated that strings would be Integer only, so your method could create an invalid output

Comment: Well...the answer(s) are based on the info provided in the question, @Bas.E. :)

Comment: But how often don't we write questions with mockup data? What if one copies this answer into production code and the system will actually take string arrays as input? Remember that the OP will not be the only one seeing (and using) this answer

Comment: @Bas.E Thanks I have added a note to my answer.

Answer (score 9):

1. Get the substring between the first and the last character in order to get rid of the `[` and `]` characters.
2. Split the resulting string by `,`.

For example:

```
String input = "[1,501,634]";
String[] result = input.substring(1, input.length() - 1).split(",");
List<String> asList = Arrays.asList(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Remove  `[` and `]` from the beginning and ending using `substring`.
2. split rest of the string according to the occurrence of `,`.

   ```
   String[] arr = multipleArray.substring( 
                       1, multipleArray.length()-1).split(",");
   ```
3. then use the array to make a list.

   ```
   List<String> list=Arrays.asList(arr);
   ```

Comment: Please add some words why you think that this is a solution.

Comment: i don't know why its necessary, yet added some explanation. @Trinimon

Comment: your answer was marked as _low quality post_ due to its short length. Personally I think it's not bad to have some explanation, even if the solution seems to be simple or obvious. Thanks!

Comment: i didn't know that low quality issue. Thank you very much. I will try to explain as best as i can, thank you again.@Trinimon

Answer (score 1):

Remove the leading and trailing square brackets:

```
String removedBrackets = multipleArray.replaceAll( "^\\[|\\]$", "" );
```

or

```
String removedBrackets = multipleArray.substring( 1, multipleArray.length() - 1 );
```

Then split the string on the commas:

```
String[] arrayOfValues = removedBrackets.split( "," );
```

Then convert it to a list:

```
List<String> listOfValues = Arrays.asList( arrayOfValues );
```

Answer (score 0):

trim it from side brackets

```
array = array.substring(1,array.length()-1);
```

then split and convert to array

```
String[] arrayStringArray = array.split(",");
```

and if wanted, make it a List

```
List<String> arrayStringList = Arrays.asList(arrayStringArray);
```